# Puppeteer xPath getting changed on AWS Lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, puppeteer

so I am using this code for scrapping an element on the basis of xPath wit Puppeteer.

```
await page.waitForXPath('//*[@id="main"]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]/a');
const [appMain] = await page.$x('//*[@id="main"]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]/a');
const appMainText = await page.evaluate(element => element.textContent.trim(), appMain);
```

This is working fine in my local computer and getting the correct data. However, when I zipped the files and uploaded on S3 bucket for AWS Lambda function, I am getting error and what I see is that the xPath changes to this:

**Error:**

> {   "error": "Waiting for selector
> `.//*[@id=\"main\"]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]/a`
> failed: Waiting failed: 30000ms exceeded" }

`.//*[@id=\"main\"]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]/a`

It adds a comma to the front and \ \ to "main".

I am not sure how this can be fixed. Would love to know a solution for this, This isn't my first AWS Lambda function, I have 3 already working fine with similar code but different URL.

**EDIT: I checked the complete DOM of the result for offline and AWS Lambda, for some reason, on AWS Lambda it's showing Cloudflare page despite using puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth. Same code is working fine offline.**

Comment: Can you provide DOM of element you're looking for?

Be aware that AWS has different location from yours and DOM on your resource in another location can be different (if they rely on it). Your selector looks easy breakable. 
Maybe you should try shorter one.

Comment: @Yaroslavm I checked the complete DOM of the result for offline and AWS Lambda, for some reason, on AWS Lambda it's showing Cloudflare page despite using puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth. Same code is working fine offline.